# Concat field value to string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, concatenation

I need a similar function to Oracle `WM_CONCAT` in SQL Server, which returns a comma separated list of whatever field you pass it as argument. For example, in Oracle,

```
select WM_CONCAT(first_name) from employee where state='CA'
```

returns "John, Jim, Bob".

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2017 STRING_AGG function has been added

```
SELECT t.name as TableName
      ,STRING_AGG(c.name, ';') AS FieldList
  FROM sys.tables t
  JOIN sys.columns c 
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
  GROUP BY t.name;
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual answer:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(buzz, 2, 2000000000)
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        firstname
    FROM 
        employee
    WHERE
        State = 'CA'
    FOR XML PATH (',')
    ) fizz(buzz)
```

A common question here. Some searches:

- [FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22for+xml+path%22)
- [concat rows csv [sql-server]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=concat+rows+csv+%5Bsql-server%5D)

Comment: Worth noting this is only valid for SQL Server 2005 and later. OP hasn't stated which version of SQL Server they're using.

Comment: You can replace the SUBSTRING, with the STUFF command which will function properly without needing to know the string length.

Comment: @Chris J: I would say that SQL 2k5 is a reasonable assumption that 10 years after SQL 2000 RTM and 2.5 versions later

Comment: 2147483647 is your friend... Memorize it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    drop table #mike_temp 
go

select * into #mike_temp 
  from (select 'Ken'  as firstname, 'CO' as state
         union all
        select 'Mike' as firstname, 'CO' as state
         union all
        select 'Tom' as firstname , 'WY' as state
       ) a
go

SELECT distinct 
       state
      ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + b.firstname FROM #mike_temp b where a.state = b.state FOR XML PATH('')),1, 2, '') AS CSVColumn
  from #mike_temp a
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to do it by yourself.

You could build an user defined function that loop with a cursor the records of Employee where the state is CA and returns the concatenation of their names.

Comment: No, no need to use a CURSOR at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Field1, Substring(Field2, 2, LEN(Field2)) AS Field2 FROM
(
    SELECT
        [InnerData].Field1,
        (SELECT  ',' + Field2 FROM @Fields WHERE Field1=[InnerData].Field1 FOR XML PATH('')) AS Field2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM @Fields
        ) AS [InnerData]
) AS OuterData
```

I got this Query from this Link

[Refer this Link for more Clarification](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.in/2008/12/string-concatenation-in-sql.html)

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
 select    
    wm_concat(name) 
 from
    employee
 where
    state='CA'
 group by
    state
```

Comment: This isn't correct.  It doesn't work in SQL Server, as the OP pointed out.  You might wish to delete it, or edit it if you meant something different?