# Create a comma seperated result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)
>   [Concat field value to string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server)

There are 2 tables involved, Users and Keywords.

**Users**
userId
firstName
lastName
...

**Keywords**
userId
keyword

If I run this query:

```
select u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName, k.keyword 
from Users as u 
inner join  Keywords as k on u.userId = k.userId
```

I get something like this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

[This looked very similar to what I wanted](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/03/31/how-to-list-multiple-rows-of-data-on-same-line.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to work right.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
       u.userId,
       u.firstName,
       u.lastName,
       (select keyword +', ' from Keywords tk where tk.userid= u.userid for xml path ('')  )   as keyword
  FROM
       Users AS u
```

Sample query to test:

```
declare @Users as table(
userid int,
firstname varchar(20),
lastname varchar(20)

)

declare @Keywords as table(
userid int,
keyword varchar(20)

)

insert into @Users
values(
1, 'Bob','Sanders'
),
(
2, 'Jamie','Smith'
)

insert into @Keywords
values 
(1,'Cars'),
(1,'Pizza'),
(2,'Tomato'),
(2,'Blah')

SELECT
       u.userId,
       u.firstName,
       u.lastName,
       (select keyword +', ' from @Keywords tk where tk.userid= u.userid for xml path ('')  )   as keyword
  FROM
       @Users AS u
```

Returns:

```
userId  firstName   lastName    keyword
1       Bob         Sanders     Cars, Pizza, 
2       Jamie       Smith       Tomato, Blah,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH a AS (
  SELECT 
    u.userId,
    u.firstName,
    u.lastName,
    ( SELECT k.keyword + ',' 
      FROM Keywords k
      WHERE k.userId = u.userId
      ORDER BY k.keyword
      FOR XML PATH('') 
    ) AS [keyword]
  FROM Users u
)
SELECT 
  a.userId,
  a.firstName,
  a.lastName,
  -- strip off trailing comma
  LEFT(
    a.keyword, 
    LEN(a.keyword)-1
  ) AS keyword
FROM a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new sql aggregate function `concat` to concatenate texts and use if in you query:

```
select userId, firstName, Lastname, concat(Keyword)
from Users
group by userId, firstName, Lastname;
```

Follwoing link shows an example on how to create the `concat` funcion. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx