# SQL Server equivalent of WM_CONCAT function

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concat field value to string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server)

What is the SQL Server equivalent of WM_CONCAT?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have an equivalent function for that, but you can still simulate (make useof `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH('')`). example,

```
USERID  ADDRESSLINE1
==========================
1       First Street
1       Second Street
2       32th Street
2       24th Street
2       25th Street
```

will result

```
USERID  ADDRESSLIST
============================
1       First Street, Second Street
2       32th Street, 24th Street, 25th Street
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT  a.UserID, 
        SUBSTRING(d.Addresses,1, LEN(d.Addresses) - 1) AddressList
FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT UserID
            FROM tableName
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT [AddressLine1] + ', ' 
            FROM tableName AS B 
            WHERE A.UserID = B.UserID 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Addresses)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/826be/3)