# The recursive coalesce challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, recursive-query, coalesce

I have a table with `Product` records and `Model` records. Both the product and model records has a `QTY` and `Size` column. For a given `product_id`, I would like to grab all `qtys` and `sizes` from the `Model` records, and place them in to the **single* `qty and size` field for the **parent** `Product` record, delimited by a pipe "`|`". Here is the sql I have so far. It successfully grabs the size and qty values from the Model records for a given product_id, but I am unable to get it to update the parent Product record fields, and do it recursively. Can someone give me a hand? Thx

This example uses product_id `'26206'`

```
--declare local variables
DECLARE
      @size_DelimitedString VARCHAR(MAX),
      @qty_DelimitedString VARCHAR(MAX)

 --pivot rows into delimited string
SELECT
      @size_DelimitedString = COALESCE(@size_DelimitedString, '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [BD New Product Data].model_size) + '|'
FROM
      [BD New Product Data]
      where record_type = 'model' and product_id = '26206'

 SELECT
      @qty_DelimitedString = COALESCE(@qty_DelimitedString, '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [BD New Product Data].model_quantity) + '|'
FROM
      [BD New Product Data]
      where record_type = 'model' and product_id = '26206'

--trim off last pipe
SET @size_DelimitedString = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@size_DelimitedString, 1, LEN(@size_DelimitedString)-1))
SET @qty_DelimitedString = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@qty_DelimitedString, 1, LEN(@qty_DelimitedString)-1)) 

--show results  
SELECT @size_DelimitedString 
SELECT @qty_DelimitedString
```

Comment: What RDBMS and version?  Oracle supports WM_CONCAT which would do this easily in versions 10g or earlier, and LIST_AGG or XML_AGG which eliminates the recursion part by combining multiple rows into 1.  SQL Server which is my guess as to what this is... uses XML Path which is a bit more complex but would work  [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559551/sql-server-equivalent-of-wm-concat-function)

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2012.Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.10.9200.16540
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.296
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: No pressure at all, but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions/10690#10690. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   product_id
 , STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.model_size)
    FROM [BD New Product Data] A 
    WHERE A.record_type = 'model' AND A.product_id = T.product_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS product_sizes
 , STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.model_quantity)
    FROM [BD New Product Data] A 
    WHERE A.record_type = 'model' AND A.product_id = T.product_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS product_quantities
FROM [BD New Product Data] T 
WHERE T.record_type = 'product' 
 --AND T.product_id = '26206'
```

Comment: This is great! Thx. So how would I take this and make it an update statement to update the qty and size fields in the product record?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation, I was pressed for time. Who knows why T-SQL doesn't offer a WM_CONCAT-like aggregate function, but it doesn't. Happily, it turns out `FOR XML PATH('')` can be used to accomplish the same thing. So the above uses XML to generate the concatenated string and then just uses STUFF() to remove the opening pipe, returning the final string. To update your qty and size fields, just change from `SELECT` to `UPDATE`, a la `UPDATE T SET product_size = STUFF(...), product_quantity = STUFF(...) FROM [BD New Product Data] T WHERE T.record_type = 'product'`.

Comment: What's missing in the final Where?

Update T
 Set T.size = STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.model_size)
    FROM [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test] A 
    WHERE A.record_type = 'model' AND A.product_id = T.sku
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
 , T.qty = STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.model_quantity)
    FROM [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test] A 
    WHERE A.record_type = 'model' AND A.product_id = T.sku
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM [dbo].[BD Active Test] T 
WHERE T.sku = A.product_id

Comment: To get it top update all product records in T, where t.sku = a.product_id

Answer (score 0):

```
USE Prod
Update dbo.[BD Active Test]
 Set dbo.[BD Active Test].size = STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test].model_size)
    FROM [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test] 
    WHERE [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test].record_type = 'model' AND [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test].product_id = dbo.[BD Active Test].sku
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
 , dbo.[BD Active Test].qty = STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test].model_quantity)
    FROM [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test] 
    WHERE [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test].record_type = 'model' AND [dbo].[BD New Product Data Test].product_id = dbo.[BD Active Test].sku
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from dbo.[BD Active Test]
INNER JOIN dbo.[BD New Product Data Test] ON dbo.[BD Active Test].sku = dbo.[BD New Product Data Test].product_id 
where dbo.[BD New Product Data Test].record_type = 'PRODUCT'
```

Comment: I'm confused, where was this `[BD Active Test]` table and the `sku` column in the original post? In terms of the solution to your problem, this answer appears to be identical to my answer.

Comment: I had left out the fact that I was updating another table. This worked out.. Thanks for your help.