# Selecting multiple rows of many to many related columns into one column in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following DB Tables with SQL Server

```
Booking(bookingID,customerName,branchID,RefNumber,...)

Trip(TripID,vehicleID,...)

BookingToTripMap(TripID,bookingID)

Branch(branchID, branchName)

Vehicle(vehicleID,vehicleNumber)
```

There is a one to one relationship between (Booking,Branch) and (Trip, Vehicle) and Many to many relationship between Booking, Trip which is saved in the table BookingToTripMap.

Now I want to extract a query that would return the following

```
Booking.RefNumber   Booking.CustomerName    Vehicle.VehicleNumber
```

(All vehicle numbers in one cell)

Comment: See at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559551/sql-server-equivalent-of-wm-concat-function

Comment: @nikhilthecoder: How is the Booking table related to Vehicle table. I did not see any relationship or foregien key in any table

Comment: Hi deepak, sorry, my mistake, it was bookingID in the Table BookingToTripMap, not vehilceID.

Comment: Have you tried something? Post your code

Comment: Best if you can also show the entity diagram or relationship information (like many-to-many, one-to-many).

Comment: Have added the rlationship mapping to the question

Comment: I think you're stuck with [FOR XML PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) ([examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx)) as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server

Comment: FWIW, here's some joining, but I gather you've got that part.  SELECT b.RefNumber, b.CustomerName, v.VehicleNumber
FROM Booking b
JOIN BookingToTripMap bt
ON bt.BookingID = b.BookingID
JOIN Trip t
ON t.TripID = bt.TripID
LEFT JOIN Vehicle v
ON v.VehicleID = t.VehicleID
LEFT JOIN Branch br
ON br.BranchID = b.BranchID

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query

```
SELECT B.RefNumber, B.CustomerName, V.VehicleNumber
FROM ((Booking AS B INNER JOIN BookingToTripMap AS BT
     ON B.bookingID = BT.bookingID) INNER JOIN TRIP as T
     ON T.TripID = BT.TripID) INNER JOIN Vehicle as V
     ON V.vehicleID = T.vehicleID
```

I would add the field bookingID to the table Trip, it seems that the table BookingToTripMap doesn't add any value to your database.

Also, if your vehicle's numbers are unique, you could change the primary key in the Vehicle table to vehicleNumber, and change the same columns in the Trip table. Thus you could retrieve the vehicleNumber directly from the Trip table.

I'm just guessing in that, based on the given information.

Regards,

Comment: I assume that the relations between (Branch, Booking) and (Trip, Vehicle) are not one to one, but one to many. Once you fix a Booking, it only corresponds to a Branch, and once you fix a Trip, maybe it has only a correspondent vehicle... But a vehicle makes many trips and the branch many bookings, right?