# Using Coallace in Sql

Tags: sql-server

How can i Convert

```
Id  Name TypeCode   UseType OptionsText
1    A     AA          1      Test1
2    B     AB          2      Test2
3    B     AB          2      Test3
```

To this

```
Id  Name TypeCode   UseType OptionsText
1    A     AA          1      Test1
2    B     AB          2      Test2;;Test3
```

I am trying to do it with **`coallace`** but not able to make it work properly.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: SQL is the language that many different database vendors implement, along with their own custom extensions.  Do you know which database PRODUCT (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) you are using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005, 2008? oracle 11g? mySQL? vendor and version help.  Coalesce doesn't do this.  in Oracle it's WM_Concat or ListAgg.)

Comment: @all i amm using SQL Server

Comment: This gives you an example of how to accomplish your desired results. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559551/sql-server-equivalent-of-wm-concat-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do so:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Name,
  t1.TypeCode,
  t1.UseType ,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ';; ' + t2.OptionsText
    FROM Tablename t2
    WHERE t2.Name   = t1.Name
      AND t1.TypeCode = t2.TypeCode
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS OptionsText
FROM Tablename t1
GROUP BY t1.Name,
      t1.TypeCode,
      t1.UseType;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4b96/13)

This will give you:

```
| NAME | TYPECODE | USETYPE |    OPTIONSTEXT |
|------|----------|---------|----------------|
|    A |       AA |       1 |          Test1 |
|    B |       AB |       2 |  Test2;; Test3 |
```

Comment: thanks its working great but its actually cutting some text from text

Comment: Its cutting the first words of the text

Comment: @Rex - Can you please update [**this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4b96/13) with the values you are working on to see the issue you have.

Comment: Replaced FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') with  this FOR XML PATH (''))  ,1,1,'') now working fine