# SQL Query with Parent relationships

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains the following type of data

```
Device     IDs
ABC        123
ABC        234
ABC        345
XYZ        123
XYZ        999
```

My SQL String that I was given (sorry I know nothing about SQL)
was

```
SELECT*
From Name123456789
```

When I import data into the tracking application I have it produces errors because `ABC` and `XYZ` are not viewed as a Parents to the IDs but instead they are viewed each as their own individual records.

Is there a way with SQL to break it out so that Device would equal `ABC` and IDs would equal `123, 234, 345`?

Desired Output ALL RECORDS BUT HAVE THE FOLLOWING format for just those two fields as there are other fields too:

```
Device     IDs
ABC        123, 234, 345
XYZ        123, 999
```

Comment: SELECT*
From Name123456789 - all it does is select ALL rows from a table called name123456789. For starters that SQL Query is probably wrong.

Comment: logixologist Thank you.  imagined that was the case.  So I am looking for a way to select all rows in the table name123456789 but would like to move the IDs as a child to Device.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please update the question with desired output. Its a little confusing what you are asking for.

Comment: logixologist, Thank you.  I updated.

Comment: what rdbms is this in?

Comment: The databae is in sql and going into an Application we use for tracking devices, RSA Archer

Comment: No, what database management system do you use: MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Comment: Sql Server for Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have (once, a while ago) done something like this in Oracle SQL using the wm_concat function.  The syntax there would be something like

```
select device,
       wm_concat(IDs) IDs
from tablename
group by device;
```

I don't use SQL server but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server) appears to show how to do the same in SQL Server.

Alternatively you could add an `order by device` then put the info from each device together in the application layer.