# Concatenating Row Values in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a particular record into one field to avoid multiple rows for the record. The issue is that a drive may contain multiple shifts in which each shift may be assigned a different vehicle.

Screenshot below shows what is happening:
[image]

Both records show the same drive, but the two shifts. I'd like to get the vehicles column to concatenate all vehicles into one field (Vehicles).

My attempt at an expression is:

```
=Fields!ShortDesc.Value & "," & Fields!ShortDesc.Value
```

Which obviously isn't working.  Any suggestions on what to do to get this working correctly?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am sorry, I updated my tags but it is MS SQL 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution would be to concat in database layer. See following [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server). If you need to use SSRS solution, answer is running value function, an example [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/101/Posts/17386/ssrs-72-use-runningvalue-function-to-concatenate-row-values.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do this on the DB layer.